# jQuery .click() event not firing on link created with .load()

Tags: jquery

The `.click()` event is firing if the menu is outside the `id="content"` (static HTML) but not working when the menu is inside the `id="content"` (dynamic HTML using `.load()`).

Click function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.type").click(function () {
        var type = $(this).data("id");
        $('#content').load("content.php?" + type);
    });
});
```

Menu link on header (click event works here):

```
<li><a data-id="1" class="type">Cars</a></li>
<li><a data-id="2" class="type">Houses</a></li>
```

`.load()` fills this (click event not working here):

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle to show an example?

Comment: The events have already been bound before the data is loaded through AJAX.  Jake Feasel's answer should fix it, but just thought you might want to know *why* it's happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change from

```
$("a.type").click(function
```

to

```
$("a.type").live('click', function
```

Or, rather than live, you could also use `$(document).on("click", "a.type", function(){})` if you are using jQuery 1.7+.

Comment: `live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+ and should not be used (use `on` instead). Even before 1.7, `delegate` should be used instead.

Comment: I think that the docs now recommend to use `on` (jquery 1.7+) or `delegate` (previous versions) rather than `live`.

Comment: not everyone has upgraded to 1.7, so I figured live was broader example to offer.

Comment: @JakeFeasel - As mentioned, even before 1.7 `live` is not recommended. Use `delegate` instead.

Comment: Also note that your `on` example won't solve the problem. It's equivalent to `.click`. You would need to bind the event handler to an ancestor element, and use the 2nd argument of `on` as a selector (in this case `a.type`). The same applies for `delegate`.

Comment: I've fixed it to reflect your point, @JamesAllardice.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks guys. Working great :)